# Creating custom template page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How to create Custom template page in wordpress.

Comment: what is views means you want show more pages

Comment: views means website hit counter, for example In some websites we can see this text line "Visited 25489 times" or "you are 1500 visitor" in the home page.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are looking for a [`HitCounter`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_counter).

Add this on your bottom of your homepage...

```
@$cont=(int)file_get_contents('counter.txt');
echo "You visited ".(int)file_get_contents('counter.txt')." times.";
file_put_contents('counter.txt',++$cont);// "prints" You visited 3 times.
```